# The parameters I'm setting seem to be messing up the code

Tags: python

new user to stackoverflow and relatively new Python user. So I'm practicing writing code by trying to make my own interactive menu(food), but when I set parameters with the != function, it doesn't seem to be working very well. Code I have so far posted below:

```
choices = ["Pizza", "Pasta", "Salad", "Nachos"]
choices_2 = ["Pizza", "pizza", "Pasta", "pasta", "Salad", "salad", "Nachos", "nachos"]
print ("Your choices are: ")
for index, item in enumerate(choices):
    print ((index+1), item)
choice = input("Which one would you like? (food item)")
for choice in choices_2:
    if choice!= choices_2: #trying to set parameters so people don't write troll answers
        input("That's not on the menu, try again: ")
    elif choice == "pizza" or "Pizza" or "pasta" or "Pasta": #trying to make Pizza and Pasta set at $4.99
        print ("That will be $4.99")
        break
    else:
        print ("That will be $1.99") #this part never comes up for some reason.
```

Answer (score 1):

`!=` stands for not equal. What you want is `not in`

```
choices = ["Pizza", "Pasta", "Salad", "Nachos"]
choices_2 = ["Pizza", "pizza", "Pasta", "pasta", "Salad", "salad", "Nachos", "nachos"]
print ("Your choices are: ")
for index, item in enumerate(choices):
    print ((index+1), item)
choice = input("Which one would you like? (food item)")
for choice in choices_2:
    if choice not in choices_2: #trying to set parameters so people don't write troll answers
        input("That's not on the menu, try again: ")
    elif choice == "pizza" or "Pizza" or "pasta" or "Pasta": #trying to make Pizza and Pasta set at $4.99
        print ("That will be $4.99")
        break
    else:
        print ("That will be $1.99") #this part never comes up for some reason.
```

Comment: also instead of `choices_2`  , you can use `choice.lower() in choices`